# How to prevent PuppeteerSharp (HTML to PDF) from starting a table row in new page when using thead tag

Tags: c#, html, css, puppeteer-sharp, dotliquid

**Problem:** When creating a PDF from a HTML template using PuppeteerSharp if you have a table with lots of data, it will create a new page if the next row doesn't fit in the current one even when there is plenty of space to start the second row, see attached image. I need the second row to start right after instead of breaking into a new page.

**What I have tried so far:** I tried removing the `<thead>` tag and when I do that then it actually utilizes the whole space as I want but then it removes the feature where every page starts with a header which I need to keep due requirements I can't change.

**Libraries used:**

- PuppeteerSharp
- DOTLiquid

**Question:**

How can I keep the `<thead>` tag and keep puppeteer from starting the table row in a new page if there is still pace available? Maybe I can create my own table headers for each page without using `<thead>`?

My HTML is a .liquid template:

```
<html>
<body>      
    <table>
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header 1</td>
                    <th>Header 2</td>
                    <th>Header 3</td>
                    <th>Header 4</td>                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
                {%for item in MyData.Items%}
                <tr>                    
                    <td style ="width: 120px">{{item.TesData}}</td>
                    <td style ="width: 120px">{{item.TesData2}}</td>
                    <td style ="width: 120px">{{item.TesData3}}</td>
                    <td style ="width: 220px">{{item.TesData4}}</td>//This column have lots of data                        
                </tr>
                {%endfor%}
         </tbody>             
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I am little late here but Did you try giving page-break-inside:auto on your table row? basically this is not puppeteersharp issue it is normal behavior for chrome print to pdf. if content doest fit in available white space it will be pushed to the new page until unless you have specified exernal rules for page break.

Comment: try this tbody > tr { page-break-inside:auto;}